# difficulty in understanding this code

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, sound

```
while abs(x(i)) <0.05     % Silence detection
    i = i + 1;
end
x(1 : i) = [];
x(6000 : 10000) = 0;
x1 = x.* w;
mx = fft(x1);

% Transform to frequency domain
nx = abs(mx(floor(mel(f))));
```

Comment: can anyone explain this code i'm new beginner in speech signal processing field and my programming skills are not good

Comment: You really need to just google for a matlab syntax guide, here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html

Comment: thanks .can you explain what does it mean these syntax x(1 : i) = [];
x(6000 : 10000) = 0;

Answer (score 2):

`x` is a sound signal, the `while` loop finds out the time point that sound first comes out. Before that, the signal is regarded as silence and removed, the signal within 6000 and 10000 elements are set to zero.

`w` is probably a window function that extracted the time zone you are interested, then the signal is converted to frequency domain. `nx` is the magnitude in frequency domain. (I am not sure what does `mel` mean, perhaps a function defined in another file)

Comment: i=i+1;is this line using for increment? can you further explain?

Comment: yes, you start from x(1), find it less than 0.05, then goto x(2), ....so on and so forth , until some x(i)>0.05

Comment: Mel function basically representation of speech on mel scale which approximate human auditory response.

Comment: ok. so it is some transformation on the original sound signal, then get the magnitude distribution after the transformation

Comment: Ok thanks one last thing is these two steps are still in confusion can you explain?x(1 : i) = []; x(6000 : 10000) = 0;

Comment: [] means removal of the elements, so x starts from signal rather than silence. and the 6000-10000 elements are set to zeros

Comment: Thanks.Suggest me how can i improve programming on matlab

Comment: coding yourself instead of use others code. When you don't know how to implement, check the possible function from Matlab help demo or online.